# Android AsyncTask, getting SharedPreferences, stuck

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm stuck with a problem that seems very easy.. I've seen lot of threads concerning my problem, but none of them helped me. It's about getting Shared Prefferences..

The thing is I want to get result from calculations in `doInBackground` method, but I just don't know how to use method `getSharedPreferences`.

I have my main activity called `MainActivity`. I also created new `Java Class` that should do something in the background. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.pablo.zad3;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Background extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Integer n = params[0];
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
       for(int i=1;i<250;i++)
       {
           sb.append(i+ " ");
           sb.append(n*i+"\n");
       }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        SharedPreferences prefs = //WHAT NOW??
    }
}
```

Yet, there's clearly something I don't understand, cause I don't know how to use it. Please provide me with some example code that would work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be modified like following:

```
package com.example.pablo.zad3;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Background extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,String>{

    private Context context;

    public Background(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Integer n = params[0];
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
       for(int i=1;i<250;i++)
       {
           sb.append(i+ " ");
           sb.append(n*i+"\n");
       }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
    }
}
```

Based on the questions you have asked (in main question along with those in comments), I guess you have never used `SharedPreferences`. Here is the link for your reference.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
http://www.pcsalt.com/android/storing-data-in-sharedpreferences-android/

Comment: Or just pass the `SharedPreferences` object to the task. It does not need the whole context.

Comment: @TmKVU can you explain? I'm new in Java/Android Studio and I really have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Same as this answer, but instead you pass the `SharedPreferences` instead of the whole context. You can just get the `SharedPreferences` in your `Activity`

Comment: thanks for answers. It's sad, I just get minused, because I am new and I don't understand answers on similar threads.

Answer (score 1):

If your AsyncTask is an inner class of some Activity, then you can do what @Alex has suggested and reference it as

```
ParentActivity.this
```

If the AsyncTask lives on its own, you will need to provide it your Context, or better yet, use callbacks in order to accomplish this task, which you can call from your onPostExecute.

```
Background task = new Background(this, ...);
task.Run();

// Your Activity will need to have some callback methods that you've decided to create
public interface BackgroundListener{
    void onBackgroundCompleted(String s);
}
```

And then in your onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    mCallback.onBackgroundCompleted(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `YourActivity`? I tried this with `MainActivity', but I get the error that it is not the enclosing class.

Comment: Then pass your activity to your Background constructor

Comment: I didn't notice you already have Context. So use thr context, I've edited the answer